# Is there a better way of getting the Drive id?

Tags: python-3.x, pywin32

I am making a DVD ripping script with MakeMKV & Handbrake and I was getting drive info and was wondering if there's a better & cleaner way of getting the Drive id?

```
from collections import namedtuple
import win32api

Drive = namedtuple(typename="Drive",
                   field_names=["title", "id", "maxfilenamlen", "sysflags", "filesystemtype"])

def get_drive_info(drive_path, new_id=None):
    Drive_list = list(win32api.GetVolumeInformation(drive_path))
    if new_id:
        Drive_list[1] = new_id
    return Drive(*Drive_list)

def get_all_cd_drives() -> list:
    cd_drives = []
    drives = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings()
    # filtering the raw string
    for drive_id, drive in enumerate(list(filter(None, drives.split('\000')))):
        # print(f"{drive=}")
        drive_info = get_drive_info(drive_path=drive)
        # Getting all DVD Drives
        if drive_info.filesystemtype == "UDF":
            cd_drives.append(get_drive_info(drive, drive_id))
    return cd_drives

# print(get_all_cd_drives()[0])
print(get_drive_info("c:\\"))
```

**Results**

`Drive(title='Test-DVD-Title', id=1, maxfilenamlen=254, sysflags=21496327, filesystemtype='UDF')`